# ¿Como retornar un nuevo observable, luego de suscribirme a otro y que este finalice?

Tags: angular, angular6, observable

Tengo un servicio el cual chequea con un webservice la validez del usuario, y de ser valido lo guarda en el localstorage.

```html
  public login(username: string, password: string) {
    const url = this.baseUrl + '/logincheck';
    this.http.post<User>(url, {username: username, password: password}).subscribe(
      currentUser => {
        currentUser.authData = window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
      }
    );
  }
```

Quisiera poder devolver un observable, el cual al suscribirme, me avise cuando todo el proceso termino (es decir, chequear el usuario con el webservice, completar el authData y guardar el usuario en el localSotrage).

¿Es posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes al menos dos opciones para devolver el valor del usuario:

- Devuelve el observable y suscríbete a él en otro componente.

```
public login(username: string, password: string) {
  const url = this.baseUrl + '/logincheck';
  return this.http.post<User>(url, {username: username, password: password}).pipe(
    tap(currentUser => {
      currentUser.authData = window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
    })
  );
}

// En el componente que haces login
this.authService.login(user, passwd).subscribe(user => {
  // Comprueba si el usuario se ha logueado
  if (user) { /* ... */ }
});
```

- Usa un [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject). En mi opinión esto es mejor ya que te puedes suscribir a él desde varios componentes/servicios. Un subject es un observable que a su vez emite observables. Tiene un método .next() para emitir el siguiente valor. En este ejemplo devolvemos el `currentUserSubject` como observable mediante la variable `currentUser`:

```
// Servicio
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public currentUser: Observable<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
  this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
}

public login(username: string, password: string) {
  const url = this.baseUrl + '/logincheck';
  return this.http.post<User>(url, {username: username, password: password})
  .pipe(
    tap(currentUser => {
      currentUser.authData = window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
      // Emitir el siguiente valor
      this.currentUserSubject.next(currentUser);
    })
  );
}

// En el componente que haces login
this.authService.login(user, passwd).subscribe(user => { /* ... */ });

// En cualquier otro componente
this.authService.currentUser.subscribe(user => { /* ... */})
```

Mírate [este tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/16/angular-7-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial), da una guía muy completa para montar autenticación en tu aplicación.

Comment: Muy buenas ambas soluciones, te hago una consulta ¿que hace tap?, porque habia visto una solucion parecida a la primera pero usando map. ¿Cual seria la diferencia entre ambos?

Comment: `map` aplica una función al valor, modificándolo si hace falta. Con `tap` puedes ver y usar los valores pero no modificarlos.